# Como verificar o remetente usando o algoritmo RSA

Tags: php, rsa

Me surgiu uma dúvida no passar de minhas pesquisas que nao consegui solucionar.

Vejamos uma forma de end-to-end que use RSA, Alice precisa uma hora enviar sua chave pública para Bob e vice versa para se comunicarem, porém se alguém executar um MITM a segurança vai ser nula, como entao verificar se a chave pública recebida do remetente é realmente Bob/Alice? Para caso nao for ignorar a mensagem.

Comment: Algoritmo Diffie-Hellman?

Answer (score 3):

Não existe um meio fácil de fazer isso, é por isso que na prática se usa **certificados** e não simples pares de chaves. Um certificado é:

- Uma chave pública...
- Associada a uma **identidade** (um nome)...
- E ambos assinados por alguém de confiança.

Digamos que Alice e Bob se conhecem, mas eles nunca trocaram chaves criptográficas entre si. Num determinado momento, alguém se dizendo ser Bob tenta iniciar uma comunicação, mostrando uma chave pública que ele diz ser de Bob. Alice não tem como saber se essa chave é ou não de Bob, a menos que ela use um **canal alternativo** para confirmar esse fato (ex.: telefonando pra Bob e pedindo pra ele dizer a "impressão digital" - *fingerprint* - da chave; assumindo é claro que ninguém consiga grampear o telefone e imitar a voz de Bob...).

Felizmente, tanto Alice quanto Bob conhecem Charlie, e ambos já trocaram chaves com Charlie. Uma maneira de Bob provar para Alice que ele e mesmo Bob é pedindo pra Charlie confirmar isso a Alice. Por exemplo, enviando uma mensagem segura pra Alice onde a chave de Bob está anexada. Isso *até funciona*, mas é muito pouco prático. Uma opção melhor é juntar a chave de Bob com o nome "Bob" e pedir pra Charlie assinar, usando sua chave privada*. Charlie conhece a chave de Bob, e sabe que ela pertence a Bob, então ele pode assinar sem problemas. Bob então pode enviar *isso* para Alice, e Alice - conhecendo a chave pública de Charlie - verifica a assinatura e confirma que a chave recebida de Bob de fato pertence a ele.

Nesse caso, Charlie estaria agindo como um **terceiro de confiança** (*trusted third-party*): se Charlie mentir pra Alice, assinando um certificado que não pertence a Bob (ex.: o nome "Bob" associado à chave pública de Mallory), não tem a princípio como Alice saber, e ela estaria vulnerável a um MitM. Por isso é importante que Alice confie bastante em Charlie, não só na sua integridade mas na sua capacidade de identificar corretamente alguém antes de assinar sua chave, e também de armazenar essas chaves com segurança.

Isso é difícil de garantir em larga escala, pois exigiria que cada um fosse *bastante* cuidadoso com todos esses aspectos. Por essa razão, na maioria dos usos práticos se opta não por deixar qualquer um assinar certificados de terceiros ([*Web of Trust*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust)), mas sim concentrar essa tarefa em umas poucas organizações, chamadas [**Autoridades Certificadoras**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoridade_de_Certifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (*Certificate Authority* - CA). Toma-se medidas para que todo mundo conheça as chaves públicas dessas CAs (por exemplo, distribuindo-as no próprio Sistema Operacional), e exige-se que todos que quiserem um certificado contratem uma delas para verificar sua identidade e assinar sua chave.

Esse sistema não é perfeito (basta uma CA ter sua chave privada comprometida para que alguém possa agir em nome de qualquer outro) mas é o que é mais usado hoje em dia (ver ["Infraestrutura de Chave Pública"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infraestrutura_de_Chaves_P%C3%BAblicas) - *Public-key infrastructure* - PKI), por exemplo quando se usa o *browser* para visitar um site que nunca foi visitado antes - o certificado contém o nome do domínio, uma chave pública, e ambos assinados por uma CA reconhecida. No contexto de um *end-to-end*, pode ser indesejável ter que confiar num terceiro para verificar a identidade dos participantes, mas a única alternativa viável seria trocar essas chaves pessoalmente e/ou usar um canal de comunicações alternativo para auxiliar na validação. Ambos muito pouco práticos, infelizmente...

---

*Nota: eu disse "chave" pra simplificar, mas na prática não se deve usar a mesma chave RSA tanto para assinar quanto pra cifrar - são necessários **dois** pares de chaves por participante para se realizar uma comunicação segura usando esse algoritmo.