# Como implementar Diffie-Hellman em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, criptografia, end-to-end

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web em que os usuários possam se comunicar um com o outro de forma privada, sem que sequer o servidor tenha acesso ao conteúdo da comunicação (i.e. [*end-to-end*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49714/215)). Para isso pretendo criptografar todas as mensagens trocadas entre eles no próprio *browser*, usando uma chave criada através do protocolo Diffie-Hellman.

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso em JavaScript? Há alguma coisa pronta no próprio *browser*, ou talvez alguma biblioteca pronta que faça isso? Ou terei que implementar à mão (no caso, usando alguma biblioteca de manipulação de inteiros de precisão arbitrária).

Finalmente: isso é suficiente para proteger a comunicação contra ataques [*Man-in-the-Middle*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7051/215)?

Answer (score 5):

A [WebCryptoAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) - em processo de padronização pela W3C e [já suportada ao menos em parte pela maioria dos *browsers* modernos](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography) - possui [métodos para geração de chaves DH](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#user-content-dh). Não é necessário, nem recomendável, fazer isso à mão, pois a possibilidade de erro é enorme (e muito provavelmente a performance será pior, se feita em JavaScript puro em vez de usar as funções fornecidas pelo próprio *browser* - muito provavelmente otimizadas em código nativo).

## Mas antes...

...um alerta: o uso de Diffie-Hellman por si só **não garante a propriedade *end-to-end***, não torna sua comunicação automaticamente segura contra MitM, e de todo modo quando feito em JavaScript a maior parte dos benefícios da criptografia se anulam. Explico:

1. Em primeiro lugar, é preciso estabelecer uma premissa básica: os usuários **confiam** no seu servidor ou não? Quando se criptografa, isso é feito por algum motivo, em geral pro caso de alguém não confiável ter acesso aos dados sendo trocados. Proteger o *canal de comunicações* é fácil: basta usar SSL/TLS. O problema são apenas os dados em repouso, em geral acessíveis pelo servidor e as pessoas que tem acesso a ele (administradores do sistema, por exemplo).

   Se esse servidor não é considerado "confiável", então temos um problema: como é ele que envia o JavaScript pro cliente, como garantir que esse JavaScript não é malicioso? Como garantir que ele não contenha um *backdoor*, ou tenha alguma outra falha proposital que anule as garantias da criptografia. Pessoalmente, eu não acho isso "inútil" como muita gente prega, mas é bom ter essa consideração em mente ao projetar um sistema com essa arquitetura...
2. > O Diffie-Hellman é um *algoritmo de troca de chaves*. A pergunta **certa** a fazer é: trocar uma chave, sim, mas com quem?
   >
   > -- [Tom Leek, no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/64409/6939)

   Se Alice e Bob querem se comunicar de forma segura, e Mallory interfere nessa comunicação, dizemos que houve um ataque *"Man-in-the-Middle"* (no caso ***wo***man in the middle, mas estou divagando...), e isso é algo que o DH se propõe a evitar. *O problema* é que uma troca de chaves DH pode ser feita de forma perfeita, mas a pessoa na outra ponta da comunicação **ser a pessoa errada!**

   Não basta Alice fazer DH com *alguém que se diz Bob*, é preciso que ela faça DH com alguém que ela *sabe* ser Bob. Do contrário, Alice pode acabar fazendo DH com Mallory, e Mallory com Bob, de modo que Alice *pensa* que está se comunicando diretamente com Bob (e vice-versa) mas na realidade essa comunicação está se dando por intermédio de Mallory (que pode ler e também alterar as mensagens trocadas).

   Caso Alice possua [algum meio de identificar Bob](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54479/215) (uma chave pública, ou talvez acesso a um CA em comum), e vice-versa, então basta que Alice **assine** os valores a serem enviados a Bob, e **verifique a assinatura** dos valores recebidos de Bob. Assim ambos saberão que estão fazendo DH com a pessoa certa.

## Um exemplo

Dados esses alertas, segue um exemplo completo do uso de DH via WebCrypto. Note que esse exemplo pode não funcionar em todos os *browsers* (no Chrome, por exemplo, só funcionaria se a página fosse servida via HTTPS):

```js
var parametros = {
    name: "DH",
    // NOTA: ESSE É UM PRIMO PEQUENO PARA TESTES SOMENTE! NÃO USE NA PRÁTICA!
    // Ver http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3526/ para primos melhores
    prime: new Uint8Array([255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,201,15,218,162,33,104,194,52,196,198,98,139,            128,220,28,209,41,2,78,8,138,103,204,116,2,11,190,166,59,19,155,34,81,74,8,            121,142,52,4,221,239,149,25,179,205,58,67,27,48,43,10,109,242,95,20,55,79,225,            53,109,109,81,194,69,228,133,181,118,98,94,126,198,244,76,66,233,166,55,237,            107,11,255,92,182,244,6,183,237,238,56,107,251,90,137,159,165,174,159,36,17,            124,75,31,230,73,40,102,81,236,228,91,61,194,0,124,184,161,99,191,5,152,218,            72,54,28,85,211,154,105,22,63,168,253,36,207,95,131,101,93,35,220,163,173,            150,28,98,243,86,32,133,82,187,158,213,41,7,112,150,150,109,103,12,53,78,74,            188,152,4,241,116,108,8,202,35,115,39,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255]),
    generator: new Uint8Array([2]),
};

// Alice gera sua chave...
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(parametros, false, ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"])
.then(function(chaves){
    var publica = chaves.publicKey;
    var privada = chaves.privateKey;
    
    // Serializa como string (base64)
    window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", publica).then(function(arraybuffer){
        var publicaStr = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arraybuffer)));
      
        // ASSINA!!!
        // ...
      
        // E envia para Bob
        // $.ajax(...)
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Pública de Alice: <pre>" + publicaStr + "</pre></p>";
        
        // Recebe a chave pública de Bob (gerada do mesmo jeito)
        // $.ajax(...)
        var bobStr = "i26tVhsmO6W8WnVu9xBROZOvFTP8n568eXZQtGR9/Ux+6RPOv4Dpkg2qVDP7gx1itY5vdC2r8KUxTfvHps3B9i6xQrlvc7CC3MY667GYp4HJge7M44dEsUTleH/xJTKITRWB7FGgfxJjQ7/z4yx5+KOD0DaLiIamPYL4XwZD3IDqbKYrngXhHNoexYAjrDskG3W0eZpy1fKJiDes9rs9ttTgSBezx+mUfBHpKUWuXzwdJhFJGnvTxW2hTna7gCER";

        // VERIFICA A ASSINATURA!!!
        // ...
      
        // Deserializa e transforma numa chave
        window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", _base64ToArrayBuffer(bobStr),
                                       parametros, false, [])
        .then(function(bob){
          
            // Junta com os parâmetros
            var parametrosMaisChave = Object.create(parametros, {
                public:{ value: bob }
            });
          
            // Duas opções:
            // 1. Deriva alguns bits comuns (mesmos derivados por Bob)
            window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits(parametrosMaisChave, privada, 256)
            .then(function(bits){
                // Os bits comuns! :)
                var bitsStr = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(bits)));
                document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Bits comuns: <pre>" + bitsStr + "</pre></p>";
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Erro ao derivar bits:<pre>" + err + "</pre></p>";
            });
          
            // 2. Deriva uma chave comum (mesma derivada por Bob) para algum algoritmo
            var parametrosChaveFinal = { 
                // o tipo de chave que você quer criar baseado nos bits derivados
                name: "AES-CTR", // pode ser qualquer algoritmo AES ("AES-CTR", "AES-CBC", "AES-CMAC", "AES-GCM", "AES-CFB", "AES-KW", "ECDH", "DH", or "HMAC")
                // Os parâmetros de geração para o tipo de algoritmo escolhido
                length: 256, //pode ser 128, 192 ou 256
            };
            window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(parametrosMaisChave, privada,
                                           parametrosChaveFinal, false,
                                           ["encrypt", "decrypt"])
            .then(function(key){
                // A chave comum! :)
                document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Combinação de chaves OK</p>";
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Erro ao combinar chaves:<pre>" + err + "</pre></p>";
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Erro ao importar chave:<pre>" + err + "</pre></p>";
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Erro ao exportar chave:<pre>" + err + "</pre></p>";
    });
})
.catch(function(err){
    document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Erro ao criar chave:<pre>" + err + "</pre></p>";
});

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/21797381/520779
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Comment: Veja, há falhas: https://jsfiddle.net/8evq62jd/

Comment: @user3163662 E quais seriam essas falhas? Se você está se referindo ao `NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported` que aparece no Firefox (opção 2), eu já tinha notado isso, e não sei se foi erro no meu código ou se o Firefox não dá mesmo suporte a essa operação... De todo modo, a derivação de bits (opção 1) funcionou corretamente. Quanto ao Chrome, o `NotSupportedError: Algorithm: Unrecognized name` está indicando que [o Chromium ainda não dá suporte a Diffie-Hellman](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto/2014Jun/0142.html), deve dar num futuro próximo.

Comment: eram estes mesmo, é um "bebe" ainda, nao acho que seja válido usa-la agora mesmo sendo o certo e sendo mais vantajoso o uso. (ps: sobre as perguntas que fiz, consegui bibliotecas boas para meus fins e continuarei a moda antiga Obrigado denovo haha!!)